# Load fragment on InfoWindowClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

So I'm trying to do the following in android xamarin.

When you press on a map element an infowindow is shown.When you press that window and an event is linked to the element the app goes to another fragment that is described by the action object. The problem is the moment I press the infowindow the whole app freezes and nothing happens. In the logs I can't see anything and the app stops at the following line:

```
pager.Adapter = pagerAdapter;
```

Added a breakpoint there and after saying "step over" the ide doesn't break anymore and the app freezes (no user interaction possible).

So let me start by giving all the relative code and a little explanation.
So first I'll show you what happens on the infowindow click. This happens on a SupportMapFragment that has it's own listener.

```
void GoogleMap.IOnInfoWindowClickListener.OnInfoWindowClick (Marker p0)
{
    InfoPopup ip = CustomJsonConverter.Convert<InfoPopup> (p0.Title);
    if (ip == null || ip.Goto == null || !(this.Activity is MainView))
        return;
    MainView main = (this.Activity as MainView);
    p0.HideInfoWindow ();
    switch (ip.Goto.type) {
        case "InfoFragment":
            Info info = InfoController.Items.Find (x => x.Index == ip.Goto.id);
            if (info != null) {
                main.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                    main.ShowInfosFragment ();
                    main.ShowInfoFragment (info);
                });
            }
            break;
        case "FaqFragment":
            FaQ faq = FaQController.Items.Find (x => x.Index == ip.Goto.id);
            if (faq != null) {
                main.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                    main.ShowFaqsFragment ();
                    main.ShowFaqFragment (faq);
                });
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I tested it with an action of InfoFragment which gives back an item so that's good. Then it goes to the main.ShowInfosFragment() which is where it freezes. So that method is really simple. This function is in the Activity holding the fragments (thanks Cheesebaron).

```
public void ShowInfosFragment(){
    ShowFragment(1, new InfosFragment (){ InfoSelectedAction = ShowInfoFragment });
}
```

So the problem giving function is the following. This function is in the Activity holding the fragments (thanks Cheesebaron).

```
protected void ShowFragment(int index, Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment, bool ignoreType = false){
    RemoveSubMenu();
    if (pagerAdapter.Count <= index || ignoreType || !(pagerAdapter.GetItem (index).GetType().Equals(fragment.GetType()))) {
        pagerAdapter.AddFragment (index, fragment);
        SetSubMenu (fragment);
        pager.Adapter = pagerAdapter;
    }
    pager.SetCurrentItem (index, true);
    DrawerButtonLayout ();
}
```

I've used this function a lot and it has always worked to move to the other fragments from the menu or at startup to set the mapfragment.

Anyone sees what's the problem with my code? Tried tons of things but can't seem to figure this one out with my friend google.

Thanks already for reading.
Kind regards,
Karl

Comment: You are inside a fragment, why not just use the `FragmentManager` inside of it to swap out the `Fragment`? Why do you need a reference to the `Activity`? Or maybe turn the signalling around. Expose an `event` and let the `Activity` have all the `Fragment` swapping logic. I can't see any reason as to why a UI element should have any of that logic.

Comment: Hello @Cheesebaron

Sorry maybe wasn't clear (will edit the text). But the ShowInfosFragment and ShowInfoFragment are in the activity which holds all the navigation logic